# How to add images on wordpress home page?

Tags: wordpress

My static front page is home and posts page is blog.Im trying to add information on home page but changes are not reflecting on homepage.How can I display images as well as their description on home page?

Comment: Please show us what you have already done.

Comment: http://www.thegeeked.in is my url have a look at it

Comment: I can add sidebar but not images.Im looking to add 7-8 images on homepage

Comment: you can use multiple feature images. https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-featured-images/

Comment: I don't want to use plugin

Comment: you can use multiple feature image code in functions.php. http://lifeonlars.com/wordpress/how-to-add-multiple-featured-images-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@S4nk37, For the given URL it seems that in your active theme directory there will be `home.php` file. You need to make a change in that file for homepage changes.
So if you are changing in `index.php` or any other file for a change in homepage, it will not reflect.